# MemoryError in Python but not IPython

Tags: python, memory, machine-learning, ipython, scikit-learn

Generally-can you think of any reason why this would happen (i.e. a MemoryError in Python but not in IPython (console--not notebook)?)

To be more specific, I'm using sklearn's `sgdclassifier` in the `multiclass` and `multilabel` case. It errors given the following code:

```
model = SGDClassifier(
    loss='hinge', 
    penalty='l2', 
    n_iter=niter, 
    alpha=alpha, 
    fit_intercept=True,
    n_jobs=1)

mc = OneVsRestClassifier(model)
mc.fit(X, y)
```

On calling `mc.fit(X, y)`, the following error occurs:

```
 File "train12-3b.py", line 411, in buildmodel
    mc.fit(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 201, in fit
    n_jobs=self.n_jobs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 88, in fit_ovr
    Y = lb.fit_transform(y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 408, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 272, in transform
    neg_label=self.neg_label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 394, in label_binarize
    Y = np.zeros((len(y), len(classes)), dtype=np.int)
MemoryError
```

`Y` is a matrix with 6 million rows and `k` columns, where the gold labels are 1 and the rest are 0 (in this case, `k = 21`, but I'd like to go >2000). `Y` gets converted by `sklearn` to a dense matrix (hence  `Y = np.zeros((len(y), len(classes)), dtype=np.int)` MemoryError ), even if it is passed in as sparse.

I have 60 gb of ram, and with 21 columns, it shouldn't take more than 8 gb max (6 million * 21 * 64), so I'm confused. I rewrote the  `Y = np.zeros((len(y), len(classes)), dtype=np.int` to use `dtype = bool`, but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Better be more specific, do you have some sample code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What are the dimensions of `X` and `y`, how much RAM do you have, and are you running 32- or 64-bit python?

Comment: X --> 6 million by 140k (sparse matrix);
Y --> 6 million by 21 (dense (well sparse, but gets converted to dense by sklearn));
60 gb ram; 64 bit python

Comment: 32- or 64-bit python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are hitting a limitation of the current implementation of the label binarizer: see issue [#2441](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2441). There is [PR #2458](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2458) to fix it.

Please feel free to try that branch and report your results as a comment to that PR.