# Parallelising hand coded OneVsRest classifier

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

Can I get help parallelising this code?  I am converting a multi-label classification problem into a OneVsRest (binary relevance) problem.  Due to memory issues mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382599/memoryerror-in-python-but-not-ipython), I am doing it manually.

```
clf_label = {}

for i, label in enumerate(label_index.keys()):
    print 'Fitting', i, 'label out of', len(label_index)
    clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', shuffle=True, alpha=0.000001, verbose=0, n_iter=5, n_jobs=4)
    temp_y = np.zeros(trainY.shape)
    temp_y[label_index[label]] = 1

    clf.fit(trainX, temp_y)
    clf_label[label] = clf
```

I am looping through the `keys` of `label_index` and building a classifier for each label.  After each classifier has been fit, I save it into another `dict` where the key is again the label but the value is the classifier.  Because of long running times, I want to parallelise this code.  Here is my attempt with `multiprocessing's` `Pool.map`:

```
def fit_label(label, trainX, trainY, label_index):
    # print 'Fitting', i, 'label out of', len(label_index)
    clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', shuffle=True, alpha=0.000001, verbose=0, n_iter=5)
    temp_y = np.zeros(trainY.shape)
    temp_y[label_index[label]] = 1

    clf.fit(trainX, temp_y)
    return clf

def linear_svm():
    p = Pool(2)
    func = partial(fit_label, trainX=trainX, trainY=trainY, label_index=label_index)
    res = p.map(func, label_index.keys()[1:6])
    clf_label = dict(zip(label_index.keys()[1:6], res))
```

and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

This seems to be quite an easy task for someone who knows how to do parallel programming in Python, so I would really appreciate if someone could rewrite this in parallel instead of modifying my (dodgy) code.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your function to parallelize outside of the function `linear_svm()` as follows:

```
def func(fit_label, trainX=None, trainY=None, label_index=None): 
    return partial(fit_label, trainX=trainX, trainY=trainY, label_index=label_index)


def linear_svm():
    numProcessors = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    p = Pool(processes=numProcessors)
    res = p.map_async(func, label_index.keys()[1:6])
    poolres = res.get()
    clf_label = dict(zip(label_index.keys()[1:6], poolres))
```